# Prevent logging in to my site if already logged in to Google using OAuth2, NodeJS, Express and Passport

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-authentication

I'm experimenting with OAuth2 Google authentication, NodeJS, Express (4.x) and Passport. I've got everything working in the sense that a user can log into the site with his or hers Google Account. But what I want to do is to automatically log in the user to my site if he's already logged into Google without displaying a login page. What's the best way to do this using this technology stack?